# How to scale up the image but prevent from cropping in ImageView?

Tags: android, rotation, imageview

I want to create an application of MEC Wheel in which there are two wheels(Images). Background image rotates through finger gesture, while foreground remains static. Also, I want that background image which is rotatable to be scale up. I have achieved it as well but when I rotate the image, it shown as crop. I am attaching the images as well.[image: This is the image when application starts]

[image: After Rotation it seem to be cropped.]

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue by scaling it through code in `onCreate()` method.

```
imgMECWheel.setScaleX(mScaleFactorBackground);
imgMECWheel.setScaleY(mScaleFactorBackground);
```